Visual Studio Android Emulator on SnapdragonX
I imagine this is going to be a common question as there doesn't seem to be a very clear way of pulling this off. I was under the impression that due to the same architecture between the AVD and the host system, emulation would be easier and faster. But alas, I can't get it to work.
Upon creating a virtual device in Visual Studio, leaving the AVD settings at default the AVD just crashes citing a GPU driver issue. The workaround provided was disabling the GPU HW acceleration, but this also resulted in a crash.
After doing some reading I found out you can install the ARM8 version of the AVD, so I tried that in both the SDK manager and the image itself. When setting the AVD to ARM8, I get a funny warning message stating that ARM8 can't be run on a host system that is x86_64.
So if anyone has figured this out, some help would be appreciated.

The processors within Android are ARM based while the processors of most PCs are x86. However, whenever you execute an ARM AVD in an x86 machine then the instructions are emulated and this may tend to be extremely slow and indefinite. Same for emulation of a GPU which adds another level of the difficulty make it even worse. Take a look at this post - https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/03/run-arm-apps-on-android-emulator.html
